# MapReduce filtering

Tags: objective-c, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a question about map reduce... I have worked with MongoDB with the aggregation pipeline (which by the way was pretty cool), but now I have turned to a CouchDB scenario.

So from what I know (maybe I'm wrong), I need to use a MapReduce.
My question is, how can I get the last 20 documents which have been written earlier than 3 days ago?
For this I guess I should do something like:

```
[viewOrderByLAstOpened setMapBlock: MAPBLOCK({
        id lastOp = [doc objectForKey: @"lastOpened"];
        NSDate* lastOpenedDate=lastOp;
        NSDate* threeDaysAgo = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-259200];
        if ((lastOp) && ([threeDaysAgo compare:lastOpenedDate] != NSOrderedDescending)) emit(lastOp, doc);
    }) version: @"1.3"];
```

But looks like I can't created 2 variables of date inside of the MapBlock.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks a lot

EDITED:

**Looks like my problem was that the compared Dates have a different format**